# Turn Facebook place into page

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

Few years ago someone created Facebook "place" of our company. It's wrong. Now we want to remove it from "places" and keep it as a normal "page".
There are two same manuals how to do that, one of them is here http://www.stuffedweb.com/change-facebook-place-into-a-facebook-page/

But in step 7 of removing my location, they mention yellow box, which I don't see (probably because of Facebook redesign). There should be a link "remove this Place" - it sound like it is definitely what I need. But it's not there.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

A Facebook Place is simply a Facebook Page with a location attached to it. Any Facebook Page (Blog, Brand, School, Website) can add or remove a physical location at any time.

To remove the "Place" from your Page, edit the page and remove the physical address.

If this doesn't resolve your problem, use the [Report a Problem](https://www.facebook.com/help/186570224871049/?ref=u2u) link on your account to let them know about the issue.

Comment: I have problem with removing the physical address.  Or should I only leave location empty? It's empty for a few months and it's still a Place. So I reported a problem and I hope someone will answer, because the whole thing is very frustrating. It's just solving a minor problem for very long time.